# atom won't run my python file even though python is in the PATH

Tags: python, path, atom-editor, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I just downloaded ubuntu on my Macbook pro and I was reinstalling my coding programs and the only problem I am currently having is atom when I try to run my python files. for C++ my files run but for python it asks me,"is it in your PATH?". I checked and python is in my path. could the problem be the initial installation of python.  [this is the message I get when I try to run a python file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCdLC.png)

Comment: open a terminal and tap python, and check if the terminal recognize it or no (to check if python is indeed in your path)

Comment: Since Atom has no capability to run code, you likely installed a *third-party package* that adds this functionality. You should specify which package you chose to install.

Comment: I installed script and its by atom-community to run python, but i remember when i downloaded that same package on my windows os it was by a different person. Also in terminal, python is recognized whenever I input "which python3" it returns where it is located and that location is indeed in my path. @idleberg

Comment: Did you follow this [suggestion](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script#atom-cant-find-node--ruby--python--my-socks) from the README?